# How to include child properties using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am having a hard time figuring this out. The examples out there are not using async calls.

How do I use `Include` when making a get call for a single object by id?

Do I need to get rid of the async call? I need to include the matching

```
ExerciseRepetitions && ExerciseImages
```

Also how could I add a

```
.Where(k => k.IsHidden != true)
```

for each child model?

```
[Route("")]
public IQueryable<Exercise> GetExercises()
{
    var result = db.Exercises
        .Include(c => c.ExerciseRepetitions)
        .Include(o => o.ExerciseImages)
        .Where(k => k.IsHidden != true);
    return result;
}

// GET: api/Exercises/5
[Route("{id:int}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(Exercise))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExercise(int id)
{
    Exercise exercise = await db.Exercises.FindAsync(id);

       ///// I need this call to return ExerciseRepetitions &&  ExerciseImages  as nested arrays. Also I need to filter out any object that has  IsHidden = true.

    if (exercise == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(exercise);
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly need to do ? It is not clear

Comment: let me update question

Comment: ok, see the comment underneath await db.Exercises

Comment: ok good to know. i can filter on client. how about just including

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't filter entities through the `Include` extension method.

You can do the following by explicit loading the collection properties. Explicit loading let you filter the collection that you're loading like this:

```
if(exercise != null)
{
    await db.Entry(exercise)
             .Collection(p => p.ExerciseRepetitions)
             .Query()
             .Where(p => !p.IsHidden)
             .LoadAsync();

    await db.Entry(exercise)
             .Collection(p => p.ExerciseImages)
             .Query()
             .Where(p => !p.IsHidden)
             .LoadAsync();
}
```

Comment: looks good, could u show me how to plug it in? Do I need to get rid of the async method and use something else?

Comment: `var exercise = db.Exercises.Find(id); if (exercise != null) { /* here comes the explicit loading */ }`

Comment: I updated my answer to ad @Gabor note and use LoadAsync async method instead of Load.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Note that for this to work properly, lazy loading must be disabled. Otherwise accessing the collections will reload them unfiltered.